# AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() rashing iPhone on startup

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1

I'm trying to find out if anyone here had mysterious crash on startup and peeking into the console logs, you see **AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed** ?

The iPhone app will connect to remote server for xml data and if the server is down this will crash the app. On subsequent startup, it will always crash until I reboot and sync to iTunes again.

I appreciate it very much if somebody can give me some clue as to how to prevent the crash or catch it and exit gracefully.

```
Sun Dec  6 22:50:31 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleFairplayTextCrypterSession::fairplayOpen() failed, error -42184
Sun Dec  6 22:50:31 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Failed to spawn MyApp. Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 140: (os/kern) failure
Sun Dec  6 22:50:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.--.MyApp[0x554b]) Exited: Killed
Sun Dec  6 22:50:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.--.MyApp[0x554b]) Throttling respawn: Will start in 2147483647 seconds
Sun Dec  6 22:50:31 unknown SpringBoard[25] <Warning>: Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue might be with this line

> Application 'MyApp' exited abnormally
>   with signal 9: Killed

Please, see this discussion

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9908695

Hope that helps

Comment: Dead ‬l‬i‬n‬k‬.